# Make this parametric plot y-axis symetrical

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I'm trying to make this plot symetrical by y-axis (even). But not sure what to do.

> ```
> {(0.79 Sqrt[-1 + y^2])/(1/4 - y), (Sqrt[15/2] Sqrt[1 + y^2])/(4 (1/4 - y))}
> ParametricPlot[%, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is to create a plot that looks like the original but flipped around the $x$-axis, you can add a second function with the $x$-coordinate flipped:

```
original = {(0.79 Sqrt[-1 + y^2])/(1/4 - y), (Sqrt[15/2] Sqrt[1 + y^2])/(4 (1/4 - y))}
flipped = {-(0.79 Sqrt[-1 + y^2])/(1/4 - y), (Sqrt[15/2] Sqrt[1 + y^2])/(4 (1/4 - y))}
ParametricPlot[{original, flipped}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: I thought I tried this, there must have been some problem with the code.
Thank you very much!